# Book access based on individual (private) access, group (restricted) access or public access

Tags: graph, gremlin, amazon-neptune

**Context**: There is a book club with books on different subjects. The book club keeps track of the book revisions but always keeps the latest revision of the books. Students can get access to the latest revision of the books based on their individual access or access granted based on the group they belong to.

***Vertices***:
(1) BOOKCLUB
(2) BOOK
(3) STUDENT
(4) GROUP

***Edges:***
(1) BOOKCLUB `hasBook` BOOK
(2) BOOK `nextRevision` BOOK
(3) STUDENT `belongsTo` GROUP
(4) BOOK `hasUserAccess` STUDENT
(5) BOOK `hasGroupAccess` GROUP

Reference test graph @ https://gremlify.com/ih6uo3q6g9/1

[Test graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjY1E.png)

```
  // Book Club
  g.addV('BOOKCLUB').property('name', 'The Bookworms').as('bc').
  
  // Book 1 with 2 revisions
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Engineering Book').as('b1').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Engineering Book v2').as('b1_v2').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Engineering Book v3').as('b1_v3').
  
  // Book 2 with 1 revision
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Medical Book').as('b2').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Medical Book v2').as('b2_v2').
  
  // Book 3 with 3 revisions
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Self Help Book').as('b3').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Self Help Book v2').as('b3_v2').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Self Help Book v3').as('b3_v3').
  addV('BOOK').property('name', 'Self Help Book v4').as('b3_v4').
  
  // SIx students
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student1').as('s1').
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student2').as('s2').
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student3').as('s3').
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student4').as('s4').
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student5').as('s5').
  addV('STUDENT').property('name', 'student6').as('s6').
  
  // Two groups
  addV('GROUP').property('name', 'Engineering Group').as('g1').
  addV('GROUP').property('name', 'Medical Group').as('g2').
  
  // Book club has those three books
  addE('hasBook').from('bc').to('b1').
  addE('hasBook').from('bc').to('b2').
  addE('hasBook').from('bc').to('b3').
  
  // Book 1 has relationship to its revisions
  addE('nextRevision').from('b1').to('b1_v2').
  addE('nextRevision').from('b1_v2').to('b1_v3').
  
  // Book 2 has relationship to its revisions
  addE('nextRevision').from('b2').to('b2_v2').
  
  // Book 3 has relationship to its revisions
  addE('nextRevision').from('b3').to('b3_v2').
  addE('nextRevision').from('b3_v2').to('b3_v3').
  addE('nextRevision').from('b3_v3').to('b3_v4').
  
  // Some students beong to groups
  addE('belongsTo').from('s1').to('g1').
  addE('belongsTo').from('s2').to('g1').
  addE('belongsTo').from('s3').to('g2').
  addE('belongsTo').from('s4').to('g2').
  
  // Some students have direct access to latest revision of books
  addE('hasUserAccess').from('b1_v3').to('s1').
  addE('hasUserAccess').from('b2_v2').to('s5').
  addE('hasUserAccess').from('b2_v2').to('s6').
  
  // Some students have access to latest revision of books via groups
  addE('hasGroupAccess').from('b1_v3').to('g1').
  addE('hasGroupAccess').from('b1_v3').to('g2')
```

**Note**: As Book 3 does not have any edge (hasUserAccess / hasGroupAccess) so it is considered a public access book available to every student.

**Query 1: Given a book club id check what latest revision of books a student has access to:**

Expected response for Student 1 (direct and via group access) -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Engineering Book v3']`
Expected response for Student 2 (via group access) -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Engineering Book v3']`
Expected response for Student 3 (via group access)  -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Engineering Book v3']`
Expected response for Student 4 (via group access) -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Engineering Book v3']`
Expected response for Student 5 (direct access) -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Medical Book v2']`
Expected response for Student 6 (direct access) -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Medical Book v2']`

**Query 2:** **Given a book club id check what latest revisions of books it has.:**

Expected response -> `['Self Help Book v4', 'Engineering Book v3', 'Medical Book v2']`

Being a novice with gremlin/graphdb I started breaking down the query into a subset like:

(1) Get the latest revision of a book (10478 is id of '`Self Help Book`' in gremlify

```
g.V('10478').
    repeat(out('nextRevision')).
    until(__.not(out('nextRevision'))).
    local(fold().limit(1))
```

The response is 10487 -> Id of '`Self Help Book v4`' in gremlify

(2) Get the books that belong to the book club

```
g.V('10460').out('hasBook')
```

The response is (manually formatted) -> initial version of the books (not the final version)

```
['Self Help Book', 'Engineering Book', 'Medical Book']
```

It's hard for me to connect the dots and create a query that traverses through the nodes and gives the expected response.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here. Is there one particular thing you are most struggling with? Knowing that will help give a focused answer.

Comment: I can get the latest versions of the books by calling `g.V('13990').out('hasBook').
  project('nxtVer').
    by(
      repeat(out('nextRevision')).
      until(__.not(out('nextRevision'))).
      local(fold().limit(1)))`
but the query does not return the book info if it does not have any versions (because `repeat` is checking for `nextRevision`).

Comment: I am able to get the latest revisions of the books using the query (a union with one part checking if there are no revisions and the other part repeating to the end of revisions):
`g.V('13990')
    .out('hasBook')
    .union(
        where(outE('nextRevision').count().is(0))
            .path()
            .by(valueMap())
            .range(local,1,-1)
            .unfold(),
        repeat(out('nextRevision'))
            .until(__.not(out('nextRevision')))
            .path()
            .tail(local)
            .valueMap())`
Not sure if this is the right optimized query.

Comment: As a next step, I need to use this set of book vertex and check if a student has access to those books (maybe a subset of them).